# Failed prop type: MUI: The getting warning in reactjs + mui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am getting below warning when I try to open datepicker on click on icon. I am getting this error.

I am doing like this

```
const DatePickerTextField = React.forwardRef((props: TextFieldProps, ref) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  return <TextField {...props} size="small" InputLabelProps={{}} />;
});
export const DDatePickerTextField = styled(DatePickerTextField)<TextFieldProps>(
  ({ theme }) => {
    return {};
  }
);

export default DDatePicker;
```

I am using like this

```
<DDatePicker
          {...restDate}
          value={value}
          onChange={callAll((newValue: Date) => {
            onChangeI(newValue);
          }, onChangeRef.current)}
          renderInput={
            !!renderInput
              ? renderInput
              : (params) => {
                  return (
                    <DDatePickerTextField
                      {...params}
                      {...textFieldProps}
                      ref={params.inputRef}
                      inputRef={ref}
                      name={name}
                      error={!!error}
                      helperText={error?.message}
                    />
                  );
                }
          }
        />
```

how to fix this issue ?

```
Warning: Failed prop type: MUI: The `anchorEl` prop provided to the component is invalid.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to pass the forwarded `ref` which `Popper.js` needs to mount the date picker component.

```js
const DatePickerTextField = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement>((props: TextFieldProps, ref) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  return <TextField {...props} size="small" InputLabelProps={{}} ref={ref} />; // passed the ref
});
```